# Namespace not working when used as variable?

Tags: php, namespaces

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package;

$test1 = new Foo\Bar(); // works as usual

$test2 = 'Foo\Bar';
$test2 = new $test2(); // does not work

$test3 = 'Vendor\Package\Foo\Bar';
$test3 = new $test3(); // but this works
```

I was looking to use `$test2` but it doesn't work even though it looks like it should as it's pretty much the same as `$test3` which worked.

Is this expected or is there some syntax I need to use for `test2` to work?

Comment: Did you mean to use `new $test3()` in the last test?

Comment: @Barmar yes fixed it thanks

Comment: Looks like when you use a variable, it has to be an absolute namespace, not interpreted relative to the current namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefix your strign with `__NAMESPACE__`

```
Vendor\Package\Foo\Bar::__construct
Vendor\Package\Foo\Bar::__construct
Vendor\Package\Foo\Bar::__construct
```

Repl.it : https://repl.it/repls/BuzzingFairSuperuser

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Foo;
class Bar
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo __METHOD__,"\n";
    }
}

namespace Vendor\Package;

$test1 = new Foo\Bar(); // works

$test2 = __NAMESPACE__.'\Foo\Bar';
$test2 = new $test2(); // works

$test3 = 'Vendor\Package\Foo\Bar';
$test3 = new $test3(); // works
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use a dynamic class name, it has to be fully qualified. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) says:

> One must use the fully qualified name (class name with namespace prefix). Note that because there is no difference between a qualified and a fully qualified Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or constant name, the leading backslash is not necessary.

`Foo\Bar` is not fully qualified, it's relative to `Vendor\Package` that you selected with the earlier `namespace` statement.

Answer (score 1):

So I'll see if I can explain this simply.  In your first instance "$test1 = new Foo\Bar();", the path to the model is mapped during compile/load time.  In the case where "$test2 = 'Foo\Bar'; $test2 = new $test2();", you're trying to call this model during runtime...  Unfortunately, at runtime, the linking has already been done, and is not revisited.  What this means it that "$test2 = '\Vendor\Package\Foo\Bar'" should work, but a shortened version of the name can't work, as the linking step is not revisited during runtime.

Comment: Use backticks to mark code in text, not double quotes.